# How do I test a long running command in aruba rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, aruba

I have an RSpec file `./spec/pkg/abc_spec.rb`, using `aruba`, with a test that routinely crashes when the command takes a long time, but does not crash if the command returns quickly.

It is failing with the stacktrace;

```
# <GEM_PATH>/aruba-2.1.0/lib/aruba/rspec.rb:35:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# <GEM_PATH>/aruba-2.1.0/lib/aruba/platforms/local_environment.rb:22:in `call'
# <GEM_PATH>/aruba-2.1.0/lib/aruba/platforms/unix_platform.rb:79:in `with_environment'
# <GEM_PATH>/aruba-2.1.0/lib/aruba/api/core.rb:222:in `block in with_environment'
# <GEM_PATH>/aruba-2.1.0/lib/aruba/platforms/unix_environment_variables.rb:189:in `nest'
# <GEM_PATH>/aruba-2.1.0/lib/aruba/api/core.rb:220:in `with_environment'
# <GEM_PATH>/aruba-2.1.0/lib/aruba/rspec.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# <GEM_PATH>/aruba-2.1.0/lib/aruba/rspec.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The spec `./spec/pkg/abc_spec.rb` in question looks like this (the actual command has been replaced with a sleep that takes as long as it);

```rb
require "aruba/rspec"

RSpec.describe "long running test", :type => :aruba do
  context "long command" do
    before { run_command('bash -c "sleep 20 && echo yikes"') }
    it { expect(last_command_started).to have_output "yikes" }
  end
end
```

Is there some way to prevent it from erroring during the testing of a command that takes a long time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aruba tests can be configured to allow long running commands. The `run_command` will respect the `exit_timeout` configuration, which can be set in the spec file such as;

```rb
Aruba.configure do |config|
  # some time longer than your run_command should take
  config.exit_timeout = 21
end
```

For the provided block, a full example using this `Aruba.configure` that works is;

```rb
require "aruba/rspec"

Aruba.configure do |config|
  config.exit_timeout = 21
end

RSpec.describe "long running test", :type => :aruba do
  context "long command" do
    before { run_command('bash -c "sleep 20 && echo yikes"') }
    it { expect(last_command_started).to have_output "yikes" }
  end
end
```